# ListView — subitem onClick() prevents onItemClick()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm extending a `CursorAdapter` to bind data to views in a `ListView`. When the sub view within the item has an `onClick()` listener, `onItemClick()` is not called for the row. I want sub view's `onClick()` method to be called, AND the `onItemClick()` method gets called, AND the row to highlight when touched (as it does by default when the sub view does not have an `onClickListener()` attached). The other touch methods (like `onLongClick()`) return a `boolean`, indicating whether the touch event was consumed, but the `onClick()` method returns void, and is acting as if it had the `boolean` returning `true`.

In my activity_main.xml I have:

```
<ListView ...[attributes] ...
    android:id="@+id/stations" >    
</ListView>
```

And for the views that populate the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout ...[attributes] ... >   
    <ImageView
        ...[attributes] ...
        android:id="@+id/station_drag" />
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        ...[attributes] ...
        android:id="@+id/station_title" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my `CursorAdapter` class:

```
public class RadioCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    protected Activity mContext;

    public RadioCursorAdapter(Activity context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.station_title);

        final String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RadioDbContract.StationEntry.COLUMN_NAME_URL));
        titleView
                .setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RadioDbContract.StationEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE)));
        // commenting out the following makes the listView's onItemClickListener
        // work, and row highlights while pressed
        titleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // this part works when the text is clicked, but prevents
                // onItemClick in listview
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_entry, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

I've tried getting the parent of `titleView`, and also its parent, and manually calling `onClick()`, but that doesn't seem to work, `onItemClick()` is a different handler. 
I've tried every combination of `android:descendantFocusability`, `android:focusable` and `android:clickable` at each level of the view hierarchy that I can think of.

Please separate any answers from other comments about what I might do differently (like not creating a new listener for each view?)

---

**Edit:**

It appears that both `setOnClickListener()` and `setOnLongClickListener()` prevent `onItemClick()` from firing on short clicks, whether `setOnLongClickListener()` returns true or false. 
Also, for either sub view to trigger the `onItemClick()`, `RelativeLayout`'s `android:descendantFocusability` should be set to `"blocksDescendants"`, and the sub views' `android:clickable` should be set to `"false"`. Nothing else seems to work or have any effect.